# Is it possible to provide value to API present class using Spring

Tags: java, spring, swing

Is there anyway so that I can provide parameter to API( not to the member of class) using Spring?
I know I can pass result of one API call to member of class

```
<bean id="registryService" class="foo.MyRegistry">
...properties set etc...
</bean>

<bean id="MyClient" class="foo.MyClient">
  <property name="endPoint" value="#{registryService.getEndPoint('bar')}"/>
</bean>
```

But, I want to pass the value to API( Basically I am trying to add `ActionListener` on `JButton` from spring)

Comment: Why do you need this? You have JButton declared in spring? You can declare ActionListener implementation in the context and get from the context to register in JButton.

Comment: @Vitaly: Actually I want to make code generalized.There is one panel on which currently I am adding JButton, in future I might change to JComboBox,JcheckBox etc.I don't want to use the code that hard code the ActionListner. What i want is when I get instance of JButton the instance of ActionListner should get attach with it from spring

Answer (score 0):

Not really a spring expert but... 
In Spring 3.

```
@Value("#{properties.getAppropriateActionListener()}")
public void setActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
   myJButton.setActionListener(listener); 
}
```

Also, I think Spring expects a setEndpoint() and getEndPoint() methods to be able to resolve the property which is named "endPoint". Declaring a property like that effectively passes the value to the setEndPoint() method. So passing a value to API (which I assume is invoking a method call) is actually pretty straightforward.

Comment: Setter without a getter is sufficient for Spring to configure a bean. Because that will be a write-only property according to Java Bean Specification.

Comment: @Nikola Kolev : "endPoint" was just example. I have asked my question after what I know. I want to set ActionListener to JButton which has addActionListener API defined already. I want to pass parameter to it.